# Are User Levels Still Currently Used?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta, capabilities, permissions

I've migrated several sites from standalone installs into a Multisite install.

For the user table, I just recreated each new user individually one by one, and readjusted the user ID's accordingly elsewhere.

Upon investigating the user meta table, it seems that WordPress is creating keys for User Levels.

As [mentioned in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels), it notes that User Levels were deprecated as of `WordPress 3.0`.

Why is it, that with a fresh installation of WordPress Multsite 4+, adding users, still creates "user_level" meta keys with values of such deprecated user level system?

Are user levels STILL used ANYWHERE in WordPress? or am I safe to simply just ignore those key/value pairs under the user meta table?

Comment: I don't have the references for this but I believe that there are a ton of database keys still there for "backwards compatibility" and those `user_level` keys are one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many plugins (and themes) use user levels, you shouldn't use them in yours. They are still used in WordPress probably to offer backward compatibility with the huge number of plugins and themes that use them.

[WPCS](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) will throw a warning whenever it busts user levels in code.